# Can I export a polygon shapefile to a Garmin device?

Tags: qgis, garmin, mac

I want to export the boundaries of a parcel to my GarminMap 60CSx. I downloaded a parcel map from the county, and I want to use it to walk the perimeter.

Does the .gpx format support polygons? Or is there some other way?

I'm on Mac, using QGIS 1.7.4.

Comment: I have the same problem I can't Import or export .GPX file to my gpsmap 62s, I suceed to take back the .gpx and register it with basecamp and after work on it with Qgis but I still don't succed to transfert the .gpx to my gps. Did you found a solution? Thanks for your answer!
Julien Brach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the GPX driver of GDAL which is used by Qgis for `Save As` does not know how to handle polygon geometries, and throws an error.

But you can convert the polygon into a line geometry using `Vector->Geometry-Tools->Polygon to line`, and export the resulting new shapefile to GPX.

Most probably you want to add `FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES` in the layer creation field, and check `Surpress attribute creation`.

And make sure the export CRS is EPSG:4326, that is WGS84 latlon.

Comment: I successfully created a new shapefile and saved the layer as a .gpx (following all your instructions), but Garmin BaseCamp rejects it as an invalid .gpx file.  I peeked into the file and saw </trkpt> delimiters but no numbers. What should I try next?

Comment: Can you import the gpx to Qgis with GPX tools? Perhaps you can share part of the gpx file here?

Comment: I was mistakenly using a database program to view the gpx file.  In a text viewer, the numbers are there.

Comment: Importing the gpx to QGIS results in a blank map.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="GDAL 1.9.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
<metadata><bounds minlat="90.000000000000000" minlon="-332624.353924790862948" maxlat="245943.600205514580011" maxlon="-180.000000000000000"/></metadata>       
<trk>
  <trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="245167.75609275419265" lon="-332624.353924790862948">
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="245197.497985753230751" lon="-332617.804893940512557">
...etc.

Comment: Oops, the coordinates are not WGS84 latlon. When exporting, you have to choose EPSG:4326. GPX does not accept any other coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a KML overlay.  I can't specifically remember how to do it manually.  Basically, it's a zip file with an internal folder structure to house images.  There's also an XML file involved which maps the images to the project space.

I collaborated on an [ArcExplorer plugin](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0d68d9d0c81e422eb8a676def5219f59) to do the heavy for this.  I realize you're on a Mac and this isn't really helpful, but you can browse the source to see what I'm doing.

https://bitbucket.org/TheGeoist/garmintools_csharp

Check out [CreateProjectFolder](https://bitbucket.org/TheGeoist/garmintools_csharp/src/649f89a1e579152878e69c854463b0c163a1c5f9/GarminTools_CSharp/GarminTools_CSharp.cs?at=default#cl-178), [CreateTile](https://bitbucket.org/TheGeoist/garmintools_csharp/src/649f89a1e579152878e69c854463b0c163a1c5f9/GarminTools_CSharp/GarminTools_CSharp.cs?at=default#cl-222) and [WriteHeader](https://bitbucket.org/TheGeoist/garmintools_csharp/src/649f89a1e579152878e69c854463b0c163a1c5f9/GarminTools_CSharp/GarminTools_CSharp.cs?at=default#cl-335)

**EDIT:** Acutally, from memory, the 60CSx doesn't support kml overlays.  You might be better off exporting the SHP to GPX in QGIS, then uploading the boundaries to the device.