# Uploading Polygon Shapefile to Garmin GPS. How to View all Polygons?

Tags: gps

I am trying to upload a polygon shapefile to a Garmin 60CSx unit. The polygon shapefile is a small area containing polygons of vegetation types. There are are 53 polygons (records) in the shapefile. I am using DNRGPS v6.0.0.15

Only one of the 53 my polygons I have uploaded appears in the GPS unit. I do not know why

This is what i have done

1. Open DNRGPS and connect to Garmin.
2. Go to File-->Load From-->File... Locate Polygon Shapefile.
3. When I choose the shapefile, the 'Select TIDENT Field' dialogue prompts and I choose a field called 'SITE'. The SITE field has the same value for all 53 records ('Forest Stand 101').
4. Now the polygons are in a table under 'Tracks'. There's 2150 Tracks. I choose Tracks-->Upload. The 'Upload To' dialogue prompts and I choose 'Named tracks'
5. GPS beeps and I have a successful upload.
6. I open GPS, go to the 'Tracks' menu and see my new track 'Forest Stand 101'. I open that track and choose the 'Map' button to view my polygons in the map.
7. This is where I notice only one of the 53 polygons is displaying. How to I get all polygons to display?

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40956/can-i-export-a-polygon-shapefile-to-a-garmin-device/40966