# Loading shapefiles onto Garmin eTrex 30

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mac, gpx, garmin

I have a Garmin eTrex 30 that I am using with QGIS 2.0.1 and Mac OS 10.9. I want to load paths from QGIS onto my Garmin so that I can view them on my Garmin map while in the field.

I have a shapefile with vector lines describing old logging roads, which I exported from QGIS as a .gpx file in UTF-8 format and WGS84 projection. I tried skipping attribute creation, also tried putting `FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES` in the Layer OGR creating field. I put the .gpx files onto my Garmin and every time I try to view them they do not show up on the screen.

However they DO show up when I open Garmin BaseCamp on my computer. Any ideas what I should try?

I've looked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40956/can-i-export-a-polygon-shapefile-to-a-garmin-device) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76271/qgis-convert-vector-points-to-gps-waypoints-and-route), and other places as well, but I can't seem to find anything that solves my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to activate your tracks from your track meny in your gps, The gpx file will create many tracks and each of them has to be activate manually. At least it works that way with other garmin gps modell.