# QGIS export to GPX: Error "Geometry type of 'multi polygon' not supported" (GPS tools)

Tags: qgis, gpx, garmin, gpstools, multi-polygon

I am trying to convert a shapefile with multiple polygons to a GPX file in QGIS 3.10.3, which has now repeatedly failed with varying export settings since "MultiPolygon" is not supported.

I have already merged all the different polygons in the shapefile, so I only have one polygon in the attribute table. Still I get this error code. Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Elena

PS: my final goal is to import these shapefiles to my Garmin Etrex Vista HCx.

Comment: I have now exported a single polygon to test with, but I still get the same error code, even though it is only one polygon object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40956/can-i-export-a-polygon-shapefile-to-a-garmin-device and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/transforming-polygon-to-linestring-in-qgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :
As AndreJ point in his comment it seem the GPX doesn't support polygon at all  (multipart or not) so have a look at the linked question to see if the solutions suit you...

A multipolygon is one polygon object that is composed of several different part (so several polygon are seen as only one object), what you need is single part polygon where each polygon are a distinct object . By merging you made all polygon become a unique multipolygon. You need to do the exact opposite, just run the multipart to single part tool (it's in Vector > Geometry tool) and try to export again.

Comment: I tried that, but I get the exact same error code again. Now I have 22 different polygons in the attribute table again, which is identical to my original shapefile.

Comment: yes, I had a look at the duplicate question and GPX doesn´t support polygon --> convert to lines and then it works. Thanks!